# Expansion of hypergeometric function with symbolic parameters

Tags: special-functions

I just tried in Mathematica 11.3

```
SeriesCoefficient[Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 2 + n, w], {w, 0, m}, Assumptions -> n > m > 1 && n \[Element] Integers]
```

which gives
$$
\frac{(n+1)! (m-n)!}{(-n)! (m+n+1)!}
$$

This cannot be correct, since $m-n<0$ and its factorial is infinity.
Is there any walkaround for this problem?

Comment: You have negative factorials in the numerator and denominator, so the ratio is regular and equal to $\frac{(-1)^m (n-1)! (n+1)!}{(n-m-1)! (n+m+1)!}$ for $n > m > 1$ and $n$,$m$ integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it was a bug.  Here's a better expression:

```
FunctionExpand@
  SeriesCoefficient[Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 2 + n, w], {w, 0, m}, 
   Assumptions -> n > m > 1 && n ∈ Integers] //. {Gamma[a_]/
   Gamma[b_] :> Pochhammer[b, a - b]}
(*  Pochhammer[1 - n, m] Pochhammer[2 + m + n, -m]  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. First, use the [Pfaff transformation](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/02/07/0001/) on your expression:

```
f = Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 2 + n, w] /. 
    Hypergeometric2F1[a_, b_, c_, z_] :> (1 - z)^(c - a - b) Hypergeometric2F1[c - a, c - b, c, z];
```

You can then apply `SeriesCoefficient[]`:

```
Assuming[m >= 0, SeriesCoefficient[f, {w, 0, m}]]
   (Gamma[m - 2 n] HypergeometricPFQ[{-m, 1 + n, 1 + 2 n}, {2 + n, 1 - m + 2 n}, 1])/
   (Gamma[1 + m] Gamma[-2 n])
```

Altho a ${}_3 F_2$ function has appeared, this is in a form where the [Saalschütz formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SaalschuetzsTheorem.html) can be applied:

```
% /. HypergeometricPFQ[{a_, b_, c_}, {d_, e_}, 1] :> 
     Pochhammer[d - b, -a] Pochhammer[d - c, -a]/(Pochhammer[d, -a] Pochhammer[d - b - c, -a])
   (Gamma[m - 2 n] Pochhammer[1, m] Pochhammer[1 - n, m])/
   (Gamma[1 + m] Gamma[-2 n] Pochhammer[-2 n, m] Pochhammer[2 + n, m])

FullSimplify[%]
   (Gamma[1 + m - n] Gamma[2 + n])/(Gamma[1 - n] Gamma[2 + m + n])
```

which is equivalent to the expression Michael obtained, but can also be rewritten as `Pochhammer[1 - n, m]/Pochhammer[n + 2, m]`. Note that this is consistent with the choice of parameters in the original hypergeometric function, since we have the identity `SeriesCoefficient[Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, w], {w, 0, m}] == (Pochhammer[a, m] Pochhammer[b, m])/(m! Pochhammer[c, m])`.